# XML conversion by using XStream : not able parse date of format 2016-02-04T18:01

Tags: java, xml, date, xml-parsing, xstream

I am converting a XML using XStream.

My XML looks like below.

```
<reportUnit>
    <creationDate>2016-02-04T18:01</creationDate>
    <description>Days Late Report</description>
    <label>Days Late Report</label>
    <permissionMask>2</permissionMask>
    <updateDate>2014-10-31T19:45</updateDate>
</reportUnit>
```

My Java code for converting the XML is like

```
XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.alias("reportUnit", ReportUnit.class);
xStream.registerConverter(
            new com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.basic.DateConverter("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", new String[] {"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"},new GregorianCalendar().getTimeZone()){
              public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
                    return type.equals(Date.class) || type.equals(Timestamp.class);
              }
              public String toString(Object obj) {
                  return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format((Date) obj);
              }
        });

xStream.fromXML(objectXml.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>", BLANK));
```

The above code works for the date format

```
<creationDate>2016-02-04 18:01</creationDate>
```

but not for the

```
<creationDate>2016-02-04T18:01</creationDate>
```

I am getting an exception as : Cannot parse date **2016-02-04T18:01**

I tried using the ISO8601DateConverter from thoughtworks available at below package

**`"com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.ISO8601DateConverter"`**

But that did not resolve my issue ...

Did anyone had the same issue and know how to resolve the same.

Comment: Try this format: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou :  waw..that very stupid thing which I didn't try....that's the answer ...I was trying only T ...Thanx for answer...You rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format was incorrect. When I used "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm" as format the it worked for me.

```
XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.alias("reportUnit", ReportUnit.class);
xStream.registerConverter(
            new com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.basic.DateConverter("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm", new String[] {"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"},new GregorianCalendar().getTimeZone()){
              public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
                    return type.equals(Date.class) || type.equals(Timestamp.class);
              }
              public String toString(Object obj) {
                  return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format((Date) obj);
              }
        });

xStream.fromXML(objectXml.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>", BLANK));
```